# how to read special characters in perl?

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file that contains the following text:

```
 óó
 é
 ó
 óóó
```

I want to be able to read this characters and manipulate them in perl.

In fact, I want to use statements such as s/ó/o/g; and so on.

When I type file -i file.txt for the file which has the text above, I get that the file is "regular file". So I think this means I don't need to take special care to treat this file in perl. However, just reading the file using  and spitting back what I read gives questions marks. So clearly something is missing.

I tried 'use bytes' in the beginning of the perl script, but that didn't help.

Any ideas how I can read this file in perl and manipulate it such as the way above?

By the way, an xxd dump of the file, contains for example:

c3b3c3b30ac3a90ac3b30ac3b3c3b3c3b30ac3b30ac3b3c3b3c3b30ac3b3

if someone needs to recover the exact characters it uses.

Comment: hint: utf-8 might help (I don't know Perl, so you might want to look it up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Perl are you using and on what platform or operating system? This should be straightforward operation if *you are using unicode throughout* (your terminal or console fonts, your `locale` settings, the file encoding, etc.)

I copied the above text into a file I created in an Xterminal using `vim`:

```
~/$ file -i utf8.txt
utf8.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
~$/ xxd  -p utf8.txttext
 c3b3c3b30ac3a90ac3b30ac3b3c3b3c3b30a
~/$ perl -npE 's/ó/o/g; s/é/ë/g' utf8.txt
 oo
 ë
 o
 ooo
```

I also used `xxd -r -p` to create a file from the dump string you included above (which was different than the one displayed in your post). The results were the same: `perl` had no issue with the accents.

Perhaps your issue is due to the text and encoding settings of your environment. If your `locale`settings, the font you are using for your terminal, or the file's encoding are inconsistent in some way you may end up with improperly displayed text.

The `perldoc` documentation for [`perlunicode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) and the tutorial [`perlunitut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) go into the necessary details if you want to understand things more thoroughly, but I'd recommend checking `LOCALE` settings and the like to begin.

Comment: thanks. what I needed to do is: open(F2, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $file).